# php merge same keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like below(figure 1). I just want to push all the sub array keys which are equal to parent array key as key values.

As an example lets say, 
parent key is 23. and 23 has a child key 24. child key 24 has sub child keys (25,26,27....) and also sub child key may have another child keys. So what I want is to push all the child, subchild, subsubchild... to parent key 23. See figure 2.

I really appreciate if someone can come up with a solution for this.

Thanks a lot..

**Figure 1**

```
Array ( [
  18] => Array ( 
    [1] =>
    [14] =>
  )
  [23] => Array ( 
    [24] =>
  ) 
  [24] => Array ( 
    [25] =>
    [26] =>
  )
 [26] => Array ( 
    [27] =>
    [28] =>
  )

)
```

**Figure 2**

```
Array ( [
  18] => Array ( 
    [1] =>
    [14] =>
  ) 
  [23] => Array ( 
    [24] => Array ( 
       [25] =>
       [26] => Array ( 
          [27] =>
          [28] =>
       )
     )
  )
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: Please format that array so it's readable.

Comment: So you want to flatten the keys of the array out into a single array?

Comment: Hello guys! @remyabel: these array keys are company id's I want to list all the sublisted companies under parent companies.

Comment: @keshu_vats:  does this comment above gives u enough detail?

Comment: @Orangepill: well, I want to shift array keys within the array as described.

Comment: @Heman I don't know about the best solution but you can create a recursive function to create such type of array

Answer (score 0):

Heh luckily, I didn't have what to do whole day at school

I left there commented echos from my quick debugging

**My Output:**

```
Array 
(
    [18] => Array
        (
        [1] =>
        [14] =>
        ) 
    [23] => Array
        ( 
        [24] => Array
            ( 
            [25] =>
            [26] => Array
                ( 
                [27] =>
                [28] =>
                )
            )
        )
)
```

**Code**

```
<?php
function test ($scan, $where="array")
{
    global $array;
    global $position;
    //echo("\r\n New dimension: ".$where);

    foreach ($scan as $key => $value)
        {
            //echo("\r\n Scanning: ".$where."[".$key."]");
            if ( !isset($position[$key]) )
            {
                $position[$key] = $where."[".$key."]";
                //echo("\r\n Key position ".$key." set on: ".$position[$key]);
                //print("\r\n $position[$key]");
            }
            else
            {
                //echo("\r\n Key ".$key." is already set on position: ".$position[$key]);
                $old = ("\$".$where."[".$key."]");
                $cmd = ("\$".$position[$key]." = &".$old);
                //print("\r\n ".$cmd);
                eval("$cmd;");
                eval("unset ($old);");
            }
            if ( is_array($value) )
            {
                //echo("\r\n Enterring: ".$where."[".$key."]");
                test($value, $position[$key]);
                //echo("\r\n Enterring: ".$where);
            }
        }
    //echo("\r\n Exiting: ".$where);
}

print_r($array);
test($array);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: You're a tunderbird. Awesome work mate. Thanks for you support. Appreciate it :)